# Overleaf PDF produces unselectable and undetectable text

Tags: pdf, overleaf

I wrote my thesis in Overleaf, but when I compile a PDF, you can not select or copy the text. Therefore my supervisor can not make comments in my PDFs and the plagiarism tool does not recognize text in my PDFs.
When I try to convert my PDF to docx via an online tool, the text is not converted to selectable text, but the tool actually makes images of every page.
How can I fix this?

I used the search bar but I mostly found questions of people asking the other way around (making text undetectable, while I want my text to be detectable).
Thanks in advance for replying!

Here is a stripped down version of my thesis document to only display "Hello world":

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}


        Hello World
    
        
   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you use pdflatex or something else for compiling?

Comment: you will have to show a small document that show which fonts you use and tell how you compile.

Comment: Thank you both for commenting! I used Overleaf.

These are the packages I used: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

Does that answer your questions? Please let me know what I can show otherwise, thanks in advance!

Comment: make a complete document with a bit text, check that it shows the problem and if yes compile and then show us the complete tex file and the log-file.

Comment: Is there any possibility that your pages have a transparent overlay?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies! What is the best way to share my files? If you send me an email on c.venema@rug.nl, then I can share everything via email if that is okay (I can not seem to find a private messaging tool here?).

There is no command used in my code for a transparent overlay by the way, so I don't think there is? Or maybe if it is default and I have to manually add a command to remove a transparent overlay?

Comment: Remove your comment with your email and just edit your question to paste your thesis reduced to a   `\documentclass{article} xxxx \begin{document} yyyy Hello World \end{document}`  where "xxxx" and "yyy" are the essential parts of the preamble and/or the contents that make  "Hello World"  unselectable and undetectable, without including anything else unrelated with the issue., e.g., if the problem is still there after removing the libertine package o a table, please do not include that package nor that table in your example code, and so on as much as you can.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already stripped down as many packages as I could. Removing the libertine package does not change anything in the PDF so I added it again as I really like the visual output of libertine.
I will now add my stripped down PDF in the opening post. Even after stripping down the packages and the content, the problem of the undetectable text in the PDF still persists. I tried mmap and cmap as they came up as a possible solution for my problem via Google, and also the T1 fontenc, but they do not solve the problem unfortunately. :\

Comment: If libertine is irrelevant for the problem at hand, remove that package! It is the task of the questioner to remove anything that distracts from the actual problem. It puts additional work on possible helpers, that could have been avoided. It is the problem that counts, not personal esthetic preferences.

Comment: This is the code without libertine:

documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}


        Hello World
    
        
   
\end{document}